# How can I use a class properties as object items for my react hook const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

So I'm trying to create a const using useState which would be properties from a class named DraftMessage that I could populate later when a value changes.

```
  const [draftMessage, setDraftMessage] = useState<DraftMessage>({
    id: undefined,
    group: undefined,
    recipients: [],
    subject: '',
    text: '',
    attachments: [],
    urgent: false,
    acknowledgementRequired: false,
    contentChanged: false,
  });
```

But I'm getting this error

> Argument of type '{ id: undefined; group: undefined; recipients: never[]; subject: string; text: string; attachments: never[]; urgent: false; acknowledgementRequired: false; contentChanged: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DraftMessage | (() => DraftMessage)'.
>     Type '{ id: undefined; group: undefined; recipients: never[]; subject: string; text: string; attachments: never[]; urgent: false; acknowledgementRequired: false; contentChanged: false; }' is missing the following properties from type 'DraftMessage': toggleUrgent, toggleAcknowledgementRequired, clean, setText, and 103 more.ts(2345).

Could anyone explain the problem happening / solutions that I could use? It's frustrating because I need to use the methods from DraftMessage and in that case, I can't...

Comment: Is DraftMessage a type or an interface?

Comment: It is a class that extends as Record

Comment: Then why are you assigning an object literal? I mean, the error clearly states that you are missing some properties (like 100+)

Comment: What do you mean by assigning an object literal? (Thanks for helping me btw)

Comment: The default state you send into the `useState<DraftMessage>()` is not a `DraftMessage`, it is an object literal, ie `{ prop: value, prop2: value }` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) )

Comment: Ooooh so I guess changing it to 

`const [draftMessage, setDraftMessage] = useState<DraftMessage>(new DraftMessage());`
would be the solution ?

Comment: Yeah :) Looks about right :)